# How to use TRIM on a VIEW

Tags: postgresql, view, trim

I have a VIEW like this:

```
SELECT * FROM test --will show:
          path        
------------------------
 /downloads/abc-dbc-abcd
 /downloads/dfg-gfd-hjkl
 /downloads/tyu-iti-titk
```

How do I use TRIM to only select the trailing part of the strings in column path?

In PostgreSQL, I've tried:

```
SELECT TRIM('/downloads/' FROM (SELECT * FROM test);
SELECT TRIM('/downloads/' FROM (SELECT path FROM test);
```

I expect to receive the output strings as just 'abc-dbc-abcd', etc.; the same as input but with '/downloads/' removed. I have been getting an error...

```
ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error are because you are using `SubQuery` in your `TRIM()` function and it returned more than 1 row so the error show.

And I prefer you use `REPLACE()` rather than `TRIM()` function here. From [*Documentation `REPLACE`*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#REPLACE) :

> Replace all occurrences in string of substring from with substring to

For the query :

```
SELECT REPLACE(path, '/downloads/', '') from test;
```

You can see here for [*Demo*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=0f92176f4ca1c8d56b4feb75ba126024)

Comment: `substring()` and `position()` also will do the job in this case  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(path,'/downloads/','')))
```